# How to use JSON which defines my language from Monarch within Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor, monarch

If I produce a JSON within Monarch for my new language syntax and I wish to use it in my Monaco editor, how can I do that? Is there a way to load this JSON? I guess there is a function which I can call to add this JSON as a language but I'm finding it difficult work out how where it is. My thinking is that it should be step by step a) make Monarch JSON b) use some Monaco API to load it and c) See it working.

Monarch here

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html

Monaco Editor here

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Comment: Is this demo of [json formatter](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/formatter/json) what you want? Then just use `defaultLanguage="json"` via [@monaco-editor/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API you are looking for is [setMonarchTokensProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#setmonarchtokensprovider)

This is also demo'ed in the [Custom languages](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages) example for Monaco Editor. The keypart is this:

```js
// Register a new language
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'mySpecialLanguage' });

// Register a tokens provider for the language
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('mySpecialLanguage', {
    tokenizer: {
        root: [
            [/\[error.*/, "custom-error"],
            [/\[notice.*/, "custom-notice"],
            [/\[info.*/, "custom-info"],
            [/\[[a-zA-Z 0-9:]+\]/, "custom-date"],
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes correct thanks https://jsfiddle.net/938uxmve/12/

Comment: I think this is still not the expected answer. I run into the same situation where I have a json file describing the syntax (for example, this one https://github.com/jlelong/vscode-latex-basics/blob/main/syntaxes/LaTeX.tmLanguage.json), the question is how to use the json file in monaco editor.

Comment: Isn't that obvious? Look at the code example in the answer. The `tokenizer` entry contains a json object.

Comment: Mike, thanks for posting the answer. Glad it's accepted too.  That said, I'd encourage you to avoid phrases like 'Isn't that obvious?' Think about it from someone new to this. They have a language file, but it's not clear the JSON is defining the tokenizer. They may not even know what a tokenizer is! They just know they have a syntax file that supposedly will give them highlighting.  Hard-coding the JSON obscures things even more.  Moving it to a `languageJSON` variable, or better yet, showing code that loads the language file would be a much clearer example and better fits the OPs question.